# Test string condition

Tags: javascript, conditional-statements

I have a **string** that is building a condition, it could read:

```
"true || false" or "false || false" or "true && false" etc..
```

I want to simply check if it passes or not.  Any suggestions?

Comment: Someone will propose `eval`. So just ahead of time: don't use `eval` without knowing exactly what that string contains (e.g. if it's user input).

Comment: You're probably barking up the wrong tree.  What's the greater purpose of this string?

Comment: Where is this string coming from?

Comment: The string is being built by a user defined option in a widget.  For instance "val1 > val2 || val2 < val1" but it could be a number of things the user is asking to check.

Comment: this can be done easily...but why put efforts in wrong direction ? if string building is under your control .. you can do it in a simple way.

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you just use a boolean instead of assembling the string?  I'm assuming you're running something like:

```
str += ' && ' + !!(Find some value)
```

Instead, track with a boolean:

```
trackingBool = trackingBool && !!(Find some value)
```

This way you avoid using a string as a boolean (an antipattern if I've ever seen one) and others reading your code have a better idea of what's going on.

Answer (score -1):

eval seems to be what I am looking for even though Ingo said not to use it ;)

Comment: `eval` should really never be used, which is why you're getting downvoted.